# Installing MySQL on Amazon EC2 Instance of Windows 2012 Server?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been looking for tutorials about installing MySQL but have found nothing that works. I am connecting to the instance via remote desktop connection, Do I have to use the command prompt to download this or can I simply open internet explorer and download it from the web? I've tried to do this but the default settings in the remote desktop are not allowing me to, I know how to change them but should I? or is there some other way of downloading MySQL.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is specifically 'how do I do it on Ec2', the answer is, 'the exact same way you would do it locally', i.e. remote desktop in and use whatever installer you normally use.

If you are talking about the 'enhanced security configuration' getting in your way, by all means shut it off (or better yet, shut it off and download chrome and use it to do the install).

Very first thing I do when I spn up an instance is turn of that 'enhanced security' for IE and download chrome into each box I need a browser on.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't want to do that because I wasn't sure if it was a bad idea.

Comment: Its only a bad idea if you (or someone with access) doesn't exercise caution when browsing from the server. If you just use it to download legitimate software, from legitimate sites, you shouldn't have a problem. IE is completely unusable with ESC turned on.